# Trouble with for developing a web application

Tags: html, css, web

I have a footer with the following code:

```
<div style="background-color: #d5d7e9; position: fixed; height: 50px; padding: 10px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;">`
```

I included this in my home page from another jsp file and it overlaps the content when scrolling. For example, when I have a table I don't see the last lines from it because of this footer.

Comment: where is the code? :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: add body{padding-bottom:50px;} in your css

Comment: If I have bigger content, the footer stays on the middle of my page over my content. I tried your codes, but it didn't work :(

Comment: just give margin :bottom 50px to table or last element before footer  so it will not overlap if you scroll to the end

Answer (score 0):

If there is, for example, an element above (`div`), then you can specify a style for it ...

```
<div style = 'padding-bottom: 10px'></div>
<div style="background-color: #d5d7e9; position: fixed; height: 50px; padding: 10px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; magin-bottom: 50"></div>
```

Comment: If I have bigger content, the footer stays on the middle of my page over my content. I tried your suggestion but it remains the same

Comment: Before your footer there is an element, there insert style

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has fixed position so is positioned relative to the browser window, overlapping any element over it.
I would edit its position:

```
position: static
```

your footer will stay under any static/relative content you will put before it and it will stay there regardles any content dimensione above.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/gbufxkuz/5/)

OR

```
position: absolute
```

You can achieve this behavior also with 'position: absolute', but the footer container must have 'position: relative' and you have less flexibility with the above content.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/gbufxkuz/3/)